# Facebook API error 200 with Two Factor Authentication

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-messenger

I'm creating a bot working with facebook messenger. It works on most pages. For some pages, I'm getting this error when trying to add a Start Button or Persistent menu :

> Facebook error: (# 200) User does not have sufficient administrative
>   permission for this action on this page. If the page requires Two
>   Factor Authentication, the user also needs to enable Two Factor
>   Authentication.

I did try to enable 2FA on all admins and contributors, and reauthorise again, doesnt work.
Anyone can shed some light ?

Comment: Was there any fix for this?

Comment: Turns out, the user that authorise the app didn't have admin role ( just an editor or something ) . Facepalm right. Facebook error message didnt help either